# MySQL: Quickly find rows that do not have a corresponding row in another table

Tags: mysql, performance

I have two tables in MySQL that are related.  I would like to find the rows in table A that do not have a corresponding row table B.  The manual and other threads here on SO recommend doing this:

```
SELECT a.id
  FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
  WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

However, this is very slow.  In my case, table A has less than 5000 rows, and table B is at around 40000, but this query is taking up to 8 minutes.

Does anybody know how to achieve this faster?

Thank you very much,
matt

EDIT: The index was the problem.  After creating one, the query runs in 10 microseconds.

Comment: Do you have your `a_id` column covered with index?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the query - it look good. Try this: `create index b_a_id on b(a_id)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Cover `a_id` field with index in `b` table
2. Replace `WHERE b.id IS NULL` with `WHERE b.a_id IS NULL`

Comment: The index was where my problem was.  Thank you very much for your time and input.

Comment: @Matt: I was first in comment and answers :-(

Comment: Yes, I thank you for your help. I did not see the comment at first.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.id
FROM a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM b
    WHERE a.id = b.a_id
)
```

And of course you should have an index on `b.a_id`

Comment: Doubtfully that mysql can optimize such queries well

Comment: @zerkms What do you mean? The database engine needs to find only one row in the corresponding table in order to get TRUE or FALSE result for `NOT EXISTS` clause. In most cases this is much faster than joins.

Comment: unfortunately mysql most likely will perform N nested queries in this case. Which is not "faster than joins" at all

Comment: @Karolis: Thank you for your input, however in my case zerkms was right.  This query is much slower than the original.  Once I created the index, the original query executed in less than 10ms, whereas this query takes 260ms.  Again, however, thank you for your help.

Comment: @zerkms You are not very objective. There are always particular situations when one or another method is better. In general the purpose of `EXISTS` clause is to test if something exists. In my opinion we should use workarounds only when the right tools do not work well. Your query needs to test about 40.000 rows. My query need to test about 5000 rows but index traversal costs more resources. So it's really difficult to say which query is better in this situation. Everything depends on particular data.

Comment: @zerkms In this particular case you won. Congratulations! :)

Comment: @Karolis: hehe, lucky me. Btw, in mysql I wouldn't ever use `EXISTS`. currently its optimization is very unpredictable. but that doesn't mean I don't use this operator in my daily work with oracle dbms ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could make it slightly faster by checking if the *foreign key* column is null, rather than the *key* (it would not account for that much slowness though):

```
SELECT a.id
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
WHERE b.a_id IS NULL;
```

If that doesn't help, try this:

```
create index b_a_id on b(a_id);
```